# How to move the column content in css?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, multiple-columns

I am working on a website in which I want to move the text towards the **left-side** bottom in css. Below is the screenshot what I want to do.

[image]

As shown in the screenshot above, I want to move the **Outburst** text towards the left-side bottom (*Aligned below character* **O**). The above screenshot is present in this [link](http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/).

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emuzps25/2/embedded/result) as well for the above link.

The **HTML code** used in the **fiddle** is generated through the following **php code**:

```
<ul id="shows-list" class="shows-list cf js-list-active">
    <?php foreach ( $alpha_programs as $title => $permalink ) :
        $title_char = substr( $title, 0, 1 ); ?>
        <li class="shows-list__letter">
        <?php
        if ( $title_char !== $prev_title_char ) : $prev_title_char = $title_char; ?>
            <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title_char ) ?></h1>
        <?php endif;?>
            <a class="shows-list__link" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><h2 class="shows-list__title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above or in the css code here in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emuzps25/2/embedded/result) so that outburst text moves towards the left-side bottom

Comment: Cause of the problem is that the HTML divides the `<li>` tags into 2 columns equally (each column has similar/equal number of items), without respecting the context (the grouping of first character of each content). To solve this problem, the easiest way is to first group the contents of each character into 1 `<div>` or `<li>` (your choice, doesn't really matter, as long as you style them properly using CSS), then use flexbox to allow automatic re-arranging of layout. Last for SEO sake, it's improper to use multiple `<h1>` in the same page; try to use `<h2>` to `<h6>` instead.

Comment: @Raptor The html which I have included [here](https://jsfiddle.net/emuzps25/2/embedded/result) is generated at run-time through php above.   There is some changes I need to do in php 1st.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try using flexbox maybe it could work like this:

```
ul #shows-list {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
```

Maybe you'll want to add:

```
justify-content: center;
```

property to center the `li`s once they're under each other.

Comment: I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle. In that way, it would be easily to visualize.

Comment: I tried to make changes in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emuzps25/2/embedded/result) here but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this.

```html
<body>
<table>
<tr>your content</tr>
<tr>your content</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: No no, absolutely no. It's 2019 now. Using table is against responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

i have checked your code and it seems you got it a little bit wrong here :

```
<ul id="shows-list" class="shows-list cf js-list-active">
 <li class="shows-list__letter">
  <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title">B</h1>
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/beyond-politics/"><h2 class="shows-list__title">Beyond Politics</h2></a>
 </li>
 <li class="shows-list__letter">
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/british-prime-ministers-question-time/"><h2 class="shows-list__title">British Prime Minister’s Question Time</h2></a>
 </li>
 <li class="shows-list__letter">
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/builders-of-canada/"><h2 class="shows-list__title">Builders of Canada</h2></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

List for links are in the same list as the alphabet. You should make a new list for links inside the alphabets lists. Like this :

```
<ul id="shows-list" class="shows-list cf js-list-active">
 <li class="shows-list__letter">
  <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title">B</h1>
  <ul class="shows-list__letter_list">
   <li class="shows-list__letter_inside">
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/beyond-politics/"><h2 class="shows-list__title">Beyond Politics</h2></a>
   </li>
   <li class="shows-list__letter_inside">
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/british-prime-ministers-question-time/"><h2 class="shows-list__title">British Prime Minister’s Question Time</h2></a>
   </li>
   <li class="shows-list__letter_inside">
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/builders-of-canada/"><h2 class="shows-list__title">Builders of Canada</h2></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

What I did is, all the links for an alphabet is put in a new list tag inside the alphabet list. Sorry for my bad English. You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emuzps25/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=emuzps25) for better understanding.